# How to pass user input variable to Sqalchemy statement?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I am fairly new to the world of programming. I'm using Python, Pandas and SQLlite; and recently I've started to build Postgresql databases.  I am trying to query a postgres database and create a Pandas dataframe with the results.  I've found that the following works:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:xxxxx@localhost:xxxx/my_postgres_db')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM my_table Where province='Saskatchewan'", engine)
```

The works perfectly but my problem is how to pass user input to the sql query.  Specifically, I want to do the following:

```
province_name = 'Saskatchewan' #user input
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM my_table Where province=province_name", engine)
```

However, this returns an error message:
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "province_selected" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM my_table Where province =province_selec...

Can anyone provide guidance on this matter?  In addition, can anyone advise me as to how to handle field names in a postgres database that have characters such as '/'.  My database has a field (column header) called CD/CSD and when I try to run a query on that field (similar to code above) I just get error messages.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the functionality provided by the DBAPI module that SQLAlchemy uses to send parameters to the query. Using psycopg2 that could look like this:

```
province_name = 'Saskatchewan' #user input
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM my_table Where province=%s", engine, params=(province_name,))
```

This is safer than using Python's string formatting to insert the parameter into the query.

[Passing parameters using psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

[`pandas.read_sql` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)